# move popup to out of screen in wpf application

Tags: wpf, popup

Maximum value of `VerticalOffset` is monitor border, how it is possible to move `Popup` to out of screen? Assume that a `Popup` want to show in right corner of screen and show `Analog Clock`, enter from out of screen.

I want to put `Popup` out of screen and enter when needed.

Answer (score 1):

there is no way on wpf framework to put Popup out of screen , but you can force popup position by calling "SetWindowPos" via p/invoke:

```
#region P/Invoke imports & definitions

        private const int HWND_TOPMOST = -1;
        private const int HWND_NOTOPMOST = -2;
        private const int HWND_BOTTOM = 1;
        private const int SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
        private const int SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
        private const int SWP_NOACTIVATE = 0x0010;
        private const int GW_HWNDPREV = 3;
        private const int GW_HWNDLAST = 1;


  [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowPos")]
        private static extern int SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, int hwndInsertAfter, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, int wFlags); 

 #endregion

 private void updateposition(Item item)
        {
            if (item.IsOpen)
            {
                IntPtr hwnd = ((HwndSource)PresentationSource.FromVisual(item.popup.Child)).Handle;
                SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, (int)item.WorkPoint.X, (int)item.WorkPoint.Y, (int)item.popup.Width, (int)item.popup.Height, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOACTIVATE);

            }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind IsOpen to something. Just like you bound PlacementTarget. I would strongly suggest using a view model so that you can bind to data. You do this by setting the DataContext property of the window. you could have a field in your view model called IsValid which is a bool then your XAML would look like this.

```
<Popup Name="myPopup2" IsOpen="{Binding IsValid}" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=mainCanvas}" Width="100" Height="100" Placement="Top" Margin="200">
```

If you implement INotifyPropertyChanged you can monitor things in the view model like text fields etc and see of the user has entered the right information etc. You might be able to do it some other way but I would urge you that using a view model and binding IsOpen to it would be the best solution.

Comment: Thank You @Kenn but the main problem is not openning or closing popup , main problem is put popup out of screen !